# react firebase signout with react query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, react-query

I was trying to migrate my codebase from redux thunks to react query so I tried implementing some of my queries as promise based queries (using fetch) in place of the traditional observers in firebase (onAuthStateChanged, onSnapshot,  etc).
On doing that, I couldn't find a way to get the auth state of the user. sign in API response was only able to return an object:

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "3N64coprOdhSPHC0z1r1060qj6L2",
    "email": "badtempler@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "[TOKEN_ID]",
    "registered": true,
    "refreshToken": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
    "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

which provided no useful information for me to deduce the current authentication state of the user.

so I want to know how I can implement that in REST as an alternative to checking it with onAuthStateChanged. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use both. React Query is great for fetching data and caching.

You should use the onAuthStateChanged listener to check for auth state and fetch user data based on the state. eg user is logged in